# Google Analytics tracking multiple domains + multiple tracker codes

Tags: google-analytics

I recently started to use multiple domain tracking code setup as outlined at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033876?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=2772342 and trying to mix that with the existing domain properties existing GA tracker codes.

But the multiple domain tracking code isn't showing any data or being picked up when I look at the multiple domain tracker web property's tracker status?

I am at a loss at what the problem is. Using GA Debugger extension for Chrome reveals 2 GA trackers outputting identical data including **identical account UA-XXXXXXX ids**.

**Background:**

- Existing web properties tracker codes are like: UA-XXXXXXX-1, UA-XXXXXXX-2 UA-XXXXXXX-3
- Multiple domain tracker codes ids are like: UA-XXXXXXY-2

I have 3 web properties all on same domain1.comm, 2 use subdomains. So all up the 3 web properties are

- domain1.com
- blog.domain1.com
- forum.domain1.com

Each property has it's own GA web property and unique tracker code for separate tracking originally. And was something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq=_gaq||[];_gaq.push(['_setAccount','UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName','domain1.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate',100]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);(function(){var ga=document.createElement('script');
ga.type='text/javascript';
ga.async=true;
ga.src=('https:'==document.location.protocol?'https://ssl':'http://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga,s);})();
</script>
```

Now I want to add a 2nd tracker to each of the 3 web properties for multiple domain tracking across all 3 web properties so set it up as follows

**for domain1.com**

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXY-2', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['forum.domain1.com, 'blog.domain1.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

**for forum.domain1.com**

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXY-2', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain1.com, 'blog.domain1.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

**for blog.domain1.com**

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXY-2', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['domain1.com, 'forum.domain1.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

**Adding SiteSpeedSampleRate**

Also to add SiteSpeedSampleRate to multiple domain tracker code, is this correct ?

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 100]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXY-2', 'domain1.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: your Adding SiteSpeedSampleRate example is mixing classic analytics and universal analytics code.   It takes 24 -48 hours for data to show up in standard reports it can take up to 75 hours for a new tracker to be picked up.  How long did you wait?

Comment: thanks for the reply, it's been coming up to 5th day since I've added the code and still no stats or detection. Yeah I realised the SiteSpeedSampleRate is incorrect and got that sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on the same domain with just different subdomains, you don't need to use the autolink. Just set the cookie domain to the highest level (domain1.com). Also, if you're running multiple trackers on the same page, you'll need to give them their own namespaces.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

/* Assuming the existing properties are migrated to Universal Aanlytics - which they should be */
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'domain1.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');

/* Note the inclusion of the name property */
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXY-2', 'domain1.com', {'name': 'multi'});
ga('multi.send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... so both need to be universal tracking codes and can not be old code + ua tracking code mix ?

Comment: You can have both at the same time, yes.